# Matlab Code to distribute points on plot

Tags: matlab

I have edited a code that i found online that helps me draw points somehow distributed on a graph based on the minimum distance between them

This is the code that i have so far

```
x(1)=rand(1)*1000;          %Random coordinates of the first point
y(1)=rand(1)*1000;

minAllowableDistance = 30;      %IF THIS IS TOO BIG, THE LOOP DOES NOT END
numberOfPoints = 300;                    % Number of points equivalent to the number of sites


keeperX = x(1);             % Initialize first point
keeperY = y(1);

counter = 2;

for k = 2 : numberOfPoints      %Dropping another point, and checking if it can be positioned

  done=0;
  trial_counter=1;

    while (done~=1)
     x(k)=rand(1)*1000;
     y(k)=rand(1)*1000;

     thisX = x(k);          % Get a trial point.
     thisY = y(k);

    % See how far is is away from existing keeper points.

     distances = sqrt((thisX-keeperX).^2 + (thisY - keeperY).^2);
     minDistance = min(distances);

     if minDistance >= minAllowableDistance
        keeperX(k) = thisX;
        keeperY(k) = thisY;
        done=1;
        trial_counter=trial_counter+1;
        counter = counter + 1;
        end

     if (trial_counter>2)
        done=1;
     end
     end

    end
end
```

So this code is working fine, but sometimes matlab is freezing if the points are above 600. The problem is full , and no more points are added so matlab is doing the work over and over. So i need to find a way when the trial_counter is larger than 2, for the point to find a space that is empty and settle there.

The trial_counter is used to drop a point if it doesn't fit on the third time.
Thank you

Comment: **warning**: if a point `k` is dropped, then `keeper(k)` will not be assigned a value until a next point (let's say k+2)  is accepted (at which time keeper(k) and keeper(k+1) will be assigned the value `0`). It is ok if you want to keep these `0` values, but if all the last `k-th` points are rejected, then `keeper` will never be assigned a value for these last points and will be shorter than `numberOfPoints`. Aside from speed considerations, this is why [preallocating](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html#f8-793781) is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `trial_counter=trial_counter+1;` is only called inside `if minDistance >= minAllowableDistance`, you will easily enter an infinite loop if `minDistance < minAllowableDistance` (e.g. if your existing points are quite closely packed).

How you do this depends on what your limitations are, but if you're looking at integer points in a set range, one possibility is to keep the points as a binary image, and use `bwdist` to work out the distance transform, then pick an acceptable point.  So each iteration would be (where `BW` is your stored "image"/2D binary matrix where 1 is the selected points):

```
D = bwdist(BW);
maybe_points = find(D>minAllowableDistance);  % list of possible locations
n = randi(length(maybe_points)); % pick one location
BW(maybe_points(n))=1; % add it to your matrix
```

(then add some checking such that if you can't find any allowable points the loop quits)

Comment: Nice one. Another useful check (even before assigning any points actually), is how many points can you fit in your domain. The max number of points you  can fit with a minimal distance `Dmin` would be: `nPointMax=(fix(width/Dmin)+1) * (fix(height/Dmin)+1)`. That would be points nicely laid on a grid in the optimal manners. Since they won't be that way, make sure from the start that your `numberOfPoints` is not higher than this value.

Comment: okey thanks guys for your answers, now I can work on a solution in a different manner using bwdist, and using the formula that @Hoki gave me